sidebase/nuxt-auth refresh token does not work well
Project Context:
I have a project using Nuxt 3, and I have integrated the sidebase/nuxt-auth module for authentication.
Detailed Description:

I have successfully installed and configured the sidebase/nuxt-auth module.
I am able to log in, and both the access token and refresh token are set correctly.
After making an auth/refresh request, the access token is updated as expected.
However, the refresh token is not updated after the auth/refresh request.

Expected vs. Actual Behavior:
I expected the refresh token to be updated along with the access token after an auth/refresh request, but only the access token is being updated.
There are no error messages in the console or server logs indicating a failure, but the refresh token simply remains unchanged.
there is my nuxt.config.ts
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: true },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        apiBaseUrl: process.env.API_BASE_URL
    },
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    modules: [
        (_options, nuxt) => {
            nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig',
                (config) => {
                    // @ts-expect-error
                    config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true }))
                })
        },
        '@vueuse/nuxt',
        '@sidebase/nuxt-auth',
    ],
    vite: {
        vue: {
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls,
            },
        },
    },
auth: {
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL + 'Auth/',
    provider: {
        type: 'refresh',
        endpoints: {
            signIn: { path: 'Login', method: 'post' },
            signOut: { path: 'Logout', method: 'post' },
            signUp: { path: 'Registration', method: 'post' },
            getSession: { path: 'GetUser', method: 'get' },
            refresh: { path: 'Refresh', method: 'post' }
        },
        token: {
            property: 'token', 
            maxAge: 1800,
            global: true,
        },
        refreshToken: {
            property: 'refreshToken',
            data: 'refreshToken',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            signInResponseRefreshTokenPointer: '/refreshToken' 
        },
    },
    sessionDataType: { username: 'string', projects: "{ id: number, name: string }[]" },
    session: {
        enableRefreshPeriodically: 1000 * 60 * 60,  
        enableRefreshOnWindowFocus: true,
    }
}
})

there is how API response for refresh looks like:
{
    "token": "ey...",
    "refreshToken": "k2..."
}

I have checked the API response to ensure the refresh token is being sent back. I have reviewed the sidebase/nuxt-auth documentation to verify my configuration. There is no any error in browser console.
The refresh token should be updated as well because the origin refresh token cannot be used twice.
